# Linked List Insert at Start Head Becomes Node, not Pointer? (Python)

Tags: python, data-structures, linked-list, logic, singly-linked-list

I have seen several implementations for inserting a node at the start of a linked list. Most go something like this (Python):

```
class Node:

    def __init__(data, next_node):
        self.__data = data
        self.__node = node

    def next(self):
        return self.__next

    def data(self):
        return self.__data

class LinkedList:

    def __init__(head):
        self.__head = head

    def insert_beginning(self, new_data):
        new_node = Node(data, self.__head)
        self.__head = new_node
```

*Rephrased for clarify:*
The code is simplified for clarity so there are some methods missing, but my question is: the head of the link list is a pointer to the first node only (no data and therefore not an actual node) - so we assign this pointer value to the next variable of our new node, so that now new_node points to the previously first node.

But from what I understand of the above code - when head is reassigned the value of new_node - it isn't pointing to that node, it contains that node. Does that make sense? Or have I some basic misunderstanding of how pointers work?

Comment: Can you rephrase your question? It is unclear what you are asking. `self.__head` is set to `new_node` because you are inserting to the beginning of the linked list.

Comment: @eugenhu tried to rephrase but not sure if it is better or worse?

Comment: in python there are no pointers. There are only names, and values. The values are "in memory", and the names (variables) you can think of them as somewhere else (even though we know they're also in memory). If you do this: `a=9; b=a; b=3`, then a will be 9, and b will be 3 at the end. Your code should work fine (except for a minor mistake in insert_beginning and Node.__init__ - you didn't use the right parameter names). Can you please provide an example of some expected behavior, and some actual behavior, and the difference between, so we can help? Cuz... your code runs fine...

Comment: You can look at it like this: In python, no variable (or name) "contains" anything. They all point to something. In C or Java (for example), the story would be completely different, but in python it's consistent. All variables "point" to the values you want, and no variable "contain" those values

Comment: @vlad-ardelean yes the code runs - the question is because I don't understand the logic behind that part of the code. So you're saying that the variable is a reference to the node in memory - therefore is essentially a pointer?

Comment: In python, all variables are references to objects in memory. Basically they all contain the memory address of the values that you want. Then, at run time, python grabs the values automatically for you, so that if you do this: `a = 9; b = 2; c = a + b; print(c)`, then you will print the expected value, 11, and not some weird memory addresses.... but you can think of all vaeiables in python as memory addresses, and python simply grabs the value at those addresses for you, so you don't have to do all that weird &x and *x stuff that C does

Comment: @vlad-ardelean great, thanks a million, that clears it up!